# how to add field label image

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to add user label image as image shown below in vue HTML to the fields but it's  not showing ... is there a way to do it?

[image]

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label for="your_pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></label>
                <input
                  class="form-control" 
                  v-model="login.password"
                  label="Password"
                  type="password"
                  minlength="6"
                 placeholder="Password"
                  required
                />
                </div>
```

Comment: You can use some CSS and HTML tricks like using nested div.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a SVG for the icon and add a small CSS to accomplish the style, like so:

```css
.form-group {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: fit-content;
}

.form-control {
  border: 0;
}

svg {
  width: 1.5ch;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="your_pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></label>
  <svg viewBox="-42 0 512 512.002" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="m210.351562 246.632812c33.882813 0 63.222657-12.152343 87.195313-36.128906 23.972656-23.972656 36.125-53.304687 36.125-87.191406 0-33.875-12.152344-63.210938-36.128906-87.191406-23.976563-23.96875-53.3125-36.121094-87.191407-36.121094-33.886718 0-63.21875 12.152344-87.191406 36.125s-36.128906 53.308594-36.128906 87.1875c0 33.886719 12.15625 63.222656 36.132812 87.195312 23.976563 23.96875 53.3125 36.125 87.1875 36.125zm0 0" />
            <path d="m426.128906 393.703125c-.691406-9.976563-2.089844-20.859375-4.148437-32.351563-2.078125-11.578124-4.753907-22.523437-7.957031-32.527343-3.308594-10.339844-7.808594-20.550781-13.371094-30.335938-5.773438-10.15625-12.554688-19-20.164063-26.277343-7.957031-7.613282-17.699219-13.734376-28.964843-18.199219-11.226563-4.441407-23.667969-6.691407-36.976563-6.691407-5.226563 0-10.28125 2.144532-20.042969 8.5-6.007812 3.917969-13.035156 8.449219-20.878906 13.460938-6.707031 4.273438-15.792969 8.277344-27.015625 11.902344-10.949219 3.542968-22.066406 5.339844-33.039063 5.339844-10.972656 0-22.085937-1.796876-33.046874-5.339844-11.210938-3.621094-20.296876-7.625-26.996094-11.898438-7.769532-4.964844-14.800782-9.496094-20.898438-13.46875-9.75-6.355468-14.808594-8.5-20.035156-8.5-13.3125 0-25.75 2.253906-36.972656 6.699219-11.257813 4.457031-21.003906 10.578125-28.96875 18.199219-7.605469 7.28125-14.390625 16.121094-20.15625 26.273437-5.558594 9.785157-10.058594 19.992188-13.371094 30.339844-3.199219 10.003906-5.875 20.945313-7.953125 32.523437-2.058594 11.476563-3.457031 22.363282-4.148437 32.363282-.679688 9.796875-1.023438 19.964844-1.023438 30.234375 0 26.726562 8.496094 48.363281 25.25 64.320312 16.546875 15.746094 38.441406 23.734375 65.066406 23.734375h246.53125c26.625 0 48.511719-7.984375 65.0625-23.734375 16.757813-15.945312 25.253906-37.585937 25.253906-64.324219-.003906-10.316406-.351562-20.492187-1.035156-30.242187zm0 0" />
        </svg>
  <input class="form-control" v-model="login.password" label="Password" type="password" minlength="6" placeholder="Password" required />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not getting the svg inside the field :/

Comment: Did you see the live example? Pres "Run code snippet", it is working.